# Select failing on hyphenated column name

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select two fields from the database, `id` an `photo-url`.

Code is:

```
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT id, photo-url FROM list ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ".$position.", ".$item_per_page."");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["id"].'. <span class="page_name">'.$row["photo-url"].'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Problem is:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>       boolean given in...(line while).

Comment: `photo-url` wrap that column name in ticks `\``. SQL is interpreting that as "photo MINUS url". Or rename it using an underscore. Somebody's going to put in an answer, so just wait for it.

Comment: Ah, knew it. lol now how did I know that.

Comment: You're welcome. Shall I make it an answer then?

Comment: Fred post it as answer you deserve the credit since you were the first

Comment: @OliverMGrech Thanks Oliver, *cheers*. I always like to explain to the OP as to why it fails, instead of just dropping a piece of code with nothing to back it with.

Comment: Totally agreed but it's a pity some (not all) people will be quick enough to leech credit(rep). Regards

Comment: @SimoneNigro OP isn't using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: @Simone he is using mysqli not mysql

Comment: @Fred-ii-  excuse me! I say it too many times!

Comment: @SimoneNigro Not a problem Simone, *cheers*

Comment: Voting to reopen because the suggested duplicate is really about debugging similar problems and not about the root cause of the failure.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`photo-url` wrap that column name in ticks. SQL is interpreting that as "photo MINUS url".

```
SELECT id, `photo-url`
```

or rename it using an underscore

```
SELECT id, photo_url
```

that way you won't have to use ticks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT `id`, `photo-url` FROM `list` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT ".$position.", ".$item_per_page."");
```

Use the `` ` `` symbol in queries to quote the names of fields or tables.